# Como retirar a borda azul do vídeo de um site?

Tags: html

[image]
Se alguém sabe como remover a borda azul do vídeo desta foto, me responda como. Desde já, agradeço a atenção !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parece ser uma borda ao focar, tente pegar o elemento que contém o vídeo e usar o pseudo seletor focus, removendo o outline

`:focus { outline: none; }`

O ideal é você alterar o estilo ao focar, pois dessa forma não irá remover o feedback visual quando um usuário está navegando com o teclado.

Comment: Mas tem que fazer uso desta função dentro da tag de vídeo ?

Comment: coloquei essa tag de vídeo dentro de um bloco da propriedade div, desde então o controle ficou aparecendo com essa borda azul. obs.: o controle é o que faz aparecer o botão de player e pause do vídeo.

Comment: pelo que lembro tem que ser na tag <video>